# Hide edit tab in editform.aspx page for a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Based on client requirement, we have customized list editform.aspx page. By default when user lands on that page, edit tab is expanded. We do not want anyone to see the ribbon on page load. We do not want to hide s4-ribbonrow. Currently I am using [This article](https://sharepoint247.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/javascript-to-hide-or-select-specific-tabs-in-sharepoint-ribbon/) to hide the edit tab on page load. But this takes lot of time (5 seconds).

Is there any other way that we can achieve this and still be fast? Please let me know your thought on this.

Environment: SharePoint Online

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this css:

```
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit {
    display: none;
}
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit-title {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This option hides "s4-titlerow" as well. We do not want to hide the title row. It should just hide the edit option and show s4-titlerow.